# 1960's well has groundwater entering

Tags: well

[image: groundwater flowing around well casing]

House was built in 1960.  Research shows that concrete 'well house' (pit) was the way it was done then.  But now groundwater is flowing around and into casing.  High flow rate.  Proposed fix is to weld casing so it is 12 inches above ground.  Are there any other requirements for a proper fix?

We are also considering some kind of structure on top of the well, similar to a doghouse to keep junk out of it.

Comment: Considering that this thing is now something like 60 years old, it may be time to abandon it and have a new well drilled and equipped according to modern standards.  I'd be afraid of putting money into this one only to have that be ineffective and end up having to drill a new well anyway.

Hire a professional well drilling service to evaluate this and give you some solid recommendations.

That should also include decommissioning this one properly so that you don't further contaminate your water supply.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the well casing above ground level is the standard approach, and works fine.

The only reason to put a (doghouse/windmill/wishing-well/lighthouse/etc.) over the extended well casing is for appearance sake (so you don't have to look at the bare well-head sticking out of the lawn.) The cap on the wellhead should do all the "keeping junk out of it" duties, the overstructure is just for appearance, if you choose.

There's absolutely no reason to "abandon your well because it's old and drill a new one" here. The risks and expense of that will be far greater, to no purpose. I presume that you'll be having a well company do the work and they will have the proper parts and experience. If you are a gung-ho home excavator and weldor planning to do the job yourself, you do have a few more parts to buy than just a section of casing. Depending where you are, that may not be legal (my LAHJ requires a licensed well driller for actual work on the well itself.)

Typically the wellhead was put in a "Pit" to keep it from freezing - you need a "pitless adapter" which goes through the side of the well casing and has a dovetail joint sealed with an o-ring that the pipe to the house connects to on the outside, and the pipe down the well connects to on the inside. That keeps the pipe below frost line. Power (assuming a submersible pump) is brought up to the cap. The cap seals the top of the well from entry of debris, and has a small screened vent (unless you happen to have a "real artesian well" where the cap needs to be a complete seal, and you don't need a pump.) It can be opened to access the well for maintenance, pump replacement, etc.

Comment: https://www.inniswelldrilling.com/the-pitless-adapter/