# Procedure for waterproofing exterior basement

Tags: basement, waterproofing, water-damage

[1960's well has groundwater entering](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/164844/1960s-well-has-groundwater-entering/164863#164863)

[Is channel in basement standard design?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/162485/is-channel-in-basement-standard-design/162512#162512)

[What should I be concerned about on this house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/163637/what-should-i-be-concerned-about-on-this-house?noredirect=1#comment275433_163637)

There have been no known problems since, but the sump pump hasn't died either.

Plan is to have contractor dig down outside and either tar or waterproof the exterior.  Also I see I can consider a drain tile.  But the issue there is the slope and depth, no where to put the water...might have to pump it from drain tile.

Best I can understand, the house is in an agricultural area and as time has gone by more people are on city water as well as less agricultural pumping of aquifer.  This has caused the water table to rise.  I believe the house is sitting on the water table - even on dry days, water is coming in the first course in basement into the channel or up through the floor.  You could see a stream running in the former well hole around the pipe (now fixed with extension).

Is it as simple as dig down to footers and waterproof?  presumably one side at a time.  What are the pitfalls here?  What if the trench fills up with water?   I have some concerns the first three courses of cinderblock are in poor shape due to the water.  Don't want to disturb things and make it worse.

I think I can make a case that this is at the higher end of technical difficulty for correcting this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If the basement floor is below the watertable, and the terrain is such that you cannot get a down-sloped drain to a lower open area to drain the water to, you are either looking at "near magical" levels of basement sealing (largely only practical when it is built in the first place and then only if it is built in the first place with that as a specific priority) or you need a working sump pump. Otherwise it will be less expensive to build another floor on the house and forget the flooded basement.